# c# return function

Tags: c#, string, textbox, return

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = "$" + (textBox1.Text = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("us-US"), "{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(textBox1.Text)));

    string digits, temp;
    long numberVal;

    string[] powers = new string[] { "Thousand ", "Million " };
    string[] ones = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen" };
    string[] tens = new string[] { "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety" };
    string[] currency = new string[] { "Dollars" };
    string wordValue = "";

    if (numberVal == 0) 
        return "Nol";
    if (numberVal < 0)
    {
        wordValue = "negative ";
        numberVal = -numberVal;
    }

    long[] partStack = new long[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int partNdx = 0;

    while (numberVal > 0)
    {
        partStack[partNdx++] = numberVal % 1000;
        numberVal /= 1000;
    }

    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        long part = partStack[i];
        if (part >= 100)
        {
            wordValue += ones[part / 100 - 1] + " Ratus ";
            part %= 100;
        }

        if (part >= 20)
        {
            if ((part % 10) != 0) wordValue += tens[part / 10 - 2] +
               " " + ones[part % 10 - 1] + " ";
            else wordValue += tens[part / 10 - 2] + " ";
        }
        else if (part > 0) wordValue += ones[part - 1] + " ";

        if (part != 0 && i > 0) wordValue += powers[i - 1];
    }

    textBox3.Text = return wordValue;

}
```

I'm trying to convert a number with long type to string word.

Why is my function returning an error, am I not using it right or something else?

Comment: What are you getting? what are you expecting?

Comment: what about simply `textBox3.Text = wordValue;` ??

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Answer (score 9):

In C#, the `return`keyword is used to return a value from a function. In your case, you're not returning anything, but you want to assign a value to some property, which is something completely different.

Remove `return` keyword.

**EDIT**
It seems you copied & pasted some code without really understanding what it does. The function you copied the code from converted a number into its text representation and returned that text representation as text.

You now try to use this code within an event handler, directly assigning the result to a textbox. That works, if you replace any `return "..."` statement by

```
{
    textbox3.Text = "...";
    return;
}
```

The cleanest solution would have been to copy the code into a function and use it correctly.

---

Example for a function that **requires** the `return` keyword:

```
string SayHello(string user)
{
    return "Hello " + user;
}
```

Example for a method that does not return a value, but can be interrupted using `return`:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    if (!myConditionIsMet)
        return;

    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Example for an assignment where you **can not** use the `return` keyword:

```
string name = "Brad";
name = name + " Pitt";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
textBox3.Text = return wordValue;
```

is not valid C# code.

Write something like:

```
 textBox3.Text = wordValue;
```

and no return, as accoridng to the function definition: `void`, there is nothing to return.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
//textBox3.Text = return wordValue;
textBox3.Text = wordValue;
```

Comment: it work, but what i 'm supposed to do with this : if (numberVal == 0) return "Nol";

Comment: You do `if (numberVal == 0) { textBox3.Text = "NOL"; return; }`. While the function you copied your code from returned the number string as a result, you now try to assign it directly to the text box. That means: You need to exit your event handler if `numberVal == 0` and instead of returning `Nol` you need to assign that text to the text box.

Comment: Since your method is "void", the return value will be just idnore here - a kind of bug

Comment: @duDE No. It is an error to return a value from a method without a return type.

Comment: Yes sure, but the OP means it works - that is why I meant it is a kind of a compiler's bug!

Comment: But you're wrong - you *can not* return a value from a "`void` method". The value will *not be ignored*, as the compiler will not let you do that in the first place. It won't even compile. And it's *not* a compiler bug!

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect
textBox3.Text = return wordValue;

Make it as follows

textBox3.Text = wordValue;

And since the function is void, there is nothing to return.

Answer (score 0):

Your method, a button_click event, has a method signiture which includes a `void` return type.

This means that the method is not intending to return anything.

Similarly, the `return` statement cannot be placed as part of an assignment statment (you can't have it to the right of the '=').

**As others have said, you will get the results you seek by simply removing the `return` keyword.  You will also need to remove the `return` statement that is further up in your code, after the check for `numberval == 0`**

The places a return are needed are methods whose header indicates a return type (anything other than `void`).  In those methods you use `return` at the start of it's own statement to return the value or object which follows it.

For instance:

```
/* In a method somewhere */
int foo = Bar();

/* The Bar method */
public int Bar()
{
    /* Whatever code runs */
    return 3; //return an object or value whose type matches the type the method signiture says you return
}
```